# converted script to .exe with py2 exe but when I run .exe nothing happens?

Tags: python, windows, exe, executable

I ran the following setup file which generated two folder called 'build' and 'dist'. In the 'dist' folder I found a file called final_project.exe. I double-clicked to launch but nothing happened. I'm running windows 7. What are the other files and folder and are they needed? I was hoping to create one executable file that I could send to others, that they could run without any other files. I also took a look at pyinstaller but had trouble getting that to work. How can I create a single executable that will work: Here's the setup code I ran to create the .exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "final_project.py"}],
    zipfile = None,)
```

Comment: Is it a GUI application where you'd expect a window to appear? Run the exe from a console (DOS box) and see what happens.

Comment: yes i should see a GUI, i did try in cmd prompt but still nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing happens because in Python you don't enjoy certain handlers like a getch() function in C that returns output to standard output or console. Alternatively you can prepare a module with a setup.py inside it, browse to the directory and simply run:

python setup.py install

OR

you can upload it to PyPi

and simply install [easy_install](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html) or [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.4.1). Then you can run:

easy_install nameofpackage/module

Comment: i dont follow your answer